# private static final double is 0

Tags: java, static, final, private-members

I am trying to use the following line to specify a double constant, can anybody help explain to me why at runtime this constant has a value of `0.0`:

```
private static final double CONSTANT = 1/2;
```

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of Alex's, but the one point I'd like to leave is that `1/2` is an *expression* (of two ints being divided) rather than a literal value.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 and 2 are interpreted as integers and produce integer result of division. Add D at the end to make them interpreted as doubles.

```
private static final double CONSTANT = 1D/2D;
```

Comment: ...and when java puts a `float` into an `int`, the decimal places are simply truncated, so `0.5` becomes `0`. Also, +1 for being first to answer

Comment: @Bohemian - where is java putting a `float` into an `int` in this example?

Comment: @StephenC is isn't, nor did I say it did. I only mention it because when the result of the integer division is mathematically a fraction the effect is *like* a `float` being put into an `int` - the non-integer part of the number is ignored

Comment: @Bohemian - a proper mathematical description of the integer `/` operator does not require you to bring real numbers (or `float`) into the picture.  The result of `N / D` operator is defined mathematically as `Q` where `N = Q * D + R`, and `0 <= R < D`.  (At least for positive `N` and `D`)

Comment: @StephenC ...or simply `floor(N / D)`, which is what I thought I was saying. nm

Comment: why not just put `.0` at the end of one of the numbers?

Comment: @Noah you can do it, too. I generally prefer `D` to clearly distinguish double from float.

Answer (score 7):

The constant ends up with a value of `0.0` because the result of integer division is an integer, truncated. So your the value of your initialization is `0`, not `0.5`. To force a `double` result, make one or both of the operands a `double`:

```
private static final double CONSTANT = 1/2.0;  // or 1/2D, or even 1D/2D
```