# Java: public static final double can't be set to decimal fraction?

Tags: java, static, double, final, fractions

I have a config file which includes some factors I want to use for calculations.

```
public class Config {

  public static final double factor = 67/300; // ~0,2233...

}
```

Im accessing the factors like this:

```
public class Calculate {

  public static calc() {
    ...
    result *= Config.factor;
    ...
```

When I do that Config.factor equals 0, so my result is 0, too. I don't have that problem if I set the factor to 0.2233, but that wouldn't be as accurate. Why doesn't setting it to 67/300 work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [private static final double is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812912/private-static-final-double-is-0)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find that question with the search. But you're right.

Comment: That's fine - your post actually has a better title. I just happened to remember that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static final double factor = 67/300d;
```

The problem is that `67` and `300` are integer literals, so the division ends up being an integer, which is 0. The `d` at the end of the number makes it a double literal, so the result of `67/300d` is a `double`.

Note that in the previous code the double literal is `300d`. You can also use `67d/300` or `67d/300d`.

Answer (score 7):

It should be something like below:

```
 public static final double factor = 67d/300d;
```

If you don't append 'd' it will be treated as integer that is why you are getting ZERO.

int will be deafault choice. As [per doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else

Answer (score 1):

When you enter 67/300, the compiler treats these as `int` rather than `double`.  Therefore, when the division occurs, the result is floored to 0.

To avoid this, cast the numbers to `double` either by adding a `d` after each number (as described in the other answers) or a full type cast with `(double)`.